# Android Low Memory: How to do factory reset of my phone when it won't open anything

Tags: ram, performance

My Android phone is constantly giving me a "Low Memory" error on the top of the screen. I would like to uninstall intensive apps or even do a factory reset (following online tutorials), but even if I open the navigator or anything else from the home-screen, the screen goes blank black and then the home-screen is restored after a while.

All the tutorials I find online to [fix the error](http://droidlessons.com/how-to-fix-low-memory-low-storage-issues-on-android/), to find which apps are eating up the memory, to [delete caches and history](http://droidlessons.com/how-to-delete-history-cleanup-your-android-device/), or to [do a factory reset](http://droidlessons.com/how-to-factory-reset-your-android-device/) involve opening Settings, and doing some operations there. But my phone won't do anything.

I also tried connecting it to my PC but it fails to connect.

So my question is that what are my options? What can I do about it? Is there a way to di a factory reset right from the home-screen without opening anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resetting a Device that's Off

1. Power down your device. Before you begin the reset procedure, you will need to completely power your device off. (If the device is frozen, you can pull the battery out to turn it off.)
2. Press and hold the recovery buttons. The buttons vary from device to device, so you may need to look up the instructions for your particular phone. You will need to press and hold the buttons for a few seconds. Some of the more common button combinations include:Volume Up + Home + PowerVolume Down + PowerHome + PowerIf none of the above work, do a web search for your phone’s model plus “recovery mode”.
3. Select Factory Reset. Once the recovery menu opens, you can navigate the menu with the volume buttons. You may need to open the Recovery menu to find the Factory Reset mode. Use the Power button, some models use the camera button, to select your menu options.You will be asked to confirm the factory reset.
4. Wait for the restore process to compete. After your phone resets, it will be set back to factory defaults and will be like it just came out of the box

Refer to this link . it has different ways for formating http://m.wikihow.com/Reset-Your-Android-Phone

Comment: Happy to help :)